# jquery ajax error message on 500 Internal Server Error different on tomcat and jetty

Tags: jquery, tomcat, error-handling, jetty

I have an ajax post call using jQuery that looks like:

```
var params = {};
params.type = "POST";
params.url = url;
params.success = successFn;
params.error = errorFn;
$.ajax(params);
```

In this case my url is a web service that intentionally throws an exception to test error handling. When I run this in jetty, the error function is called with the exception text. When I run this in Tomcat, the error function just comes back with "Internal Server Error".

In both cases, I see the exception thrown on the server, but the message that comes back to the browser is different.

Is this something that I need to handle at an application level? Or is there a tomcat configuration for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Jetty and Tomcat are handling the response differently.

Take a look at the `Content-Type` HTTP header, the HTTP status code returned by the server, and see if any error handlers are redirecting the response on the server before it makes it to the client.

Some pseudo code that might serve as an example of what might work on the server:

```
HttpServletResponse resp; // likely passed in as argument

resp.setContentType("application/json");
try {
    // do something
} catch (Exception e) {
    String jsonError = "{\"error\":\"" + e.getMessage() + "\"}";
    resp.getWriter().print(jsonError);
    resp.sendError(500);
}
```

This way you should be able to use JQuery's `$.ajaxError()` event handler and parse the error message.

Comment: both are handling content type but the resp.sendError is  what i needed